# MYSQL creates index automatically when

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have the following main table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_1` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_2` (
  `id_1` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_2` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`,`id_2`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_1`) REFERENCES table_1(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_2`) REFERENCES table_2(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For some reason when creating the above tables, I get the following index created automatically by MYSQL:

```
    Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation Null  
      id_2  BTREE     No       No   id_2    94695       A      No
```

So MYSQL is creating an index on the second column called `id_2` in `table_2`. Strange enough, it's not created on both foreign keys and if I create only 1 foreign key, MYSQL wouldn't create an index like this.

I tried to drop the index and got the following error:

```
 Cannot drop index 'id_2': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

So why does MYSQL need to create an index like this and why it's created on both keys??

Comment: But there is no `id` in `table_2`! ? !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike other databases, MySQL creates indexes for foreign key constraints.  As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> index_name represents a foreign key ID. The index_name value is
>   ignored if there is already an explicitly defined index on the child
>   table that can support the foreign key. Otherwise, MySQL implicitly creates a foreign key index that is named according to the following rules:
>   . . .

In your case, one of the foreign key declarations is handled by the primary key index, because `id_1` is the first key in both of them.